# admob and activity

Tags: android, admob, android-activity

I've been trying to set this for the last couple of weeks but with no success. How can I put these 2 blocks of code in the same Java class?

```
private int entries = 6;
private String phoneNum[];
private String buttonLabels[];

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    phoneNum = new String[entries];
    buttonLabels = new String[entries];

    // Populate the data arrays
    populateArrays();

    // Set up buttons and attach click listeners

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setText(buttonLabels[0]);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setText(buttonLabels[1]);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setText(buttonLabels[2]);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setText(buttonLabels[3]);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button5.setText(buttonLabels[4]);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button6.setText(buttonLabels[5]);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
}

// Launch the phone dialer

public void launchDialer(String number){
    String numberToDial = "tel:"+number;
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(numberToDial)));
}


/** Method to populate the data arrays */

public void populateArrays(){

    /** In a practical application the arrays phoneNum and buttonLabels could be 
     * updated dynamically from the Web in this method.  For this project we just 
     * hard-wire in some values to illustrate how to use such data, once obtained,
     * to make phone calls.*/

    phoneNum[0] = "000-000-0001";
    phoneNum[1] = "000-000-0002";
    phoneNum[2] = "000-000-0003";
    phoneNum[3] = "000-000-0004";
    phoneNum[4] = "000-000-0005";
    phoneNum[5] = "000-000-0006";

    buttonLabels[0] = "Jane D. Arc";
    buttonLabels[1] = "John Doe";
    buttonLabels[2] = "Jane Doe";
    buttonLabels[3] = "Abe Linking";
    buttonLabels[4] = "Mona Liza";
    buttonLabels[5] = "Issac Nuton";
}

/** Process button events */

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[0]);
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[1]);
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[2]);
            break;

        case R.id.button4:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[3]);
            break;

        case R.id.button5:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[4]);
            break;

        case R.id.button6:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[5]);
            break;

    }
}
```

When I try to override `onStart()`, the app crashes.

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    AdView layout = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.setTesting(true);
    layout.loadAd(adRequest); 
}
```

I know that the issue is this line:

```
public void onStart(){
```

Comment: I don't really understand... have you try to put @Override over the "public void onStart(){" line?

Comment: yes i did. the thing is, when i put the code each one of a time, the apps dosent crash, but when i put the two blocks the app crashes.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace of the crash?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get AdMob to work, you shouldn't use onStart. Use your onCreate instead.

It's in the [Google Admob documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals) under the **Adding a com.google.ads.AdView** section.

If you already have an AdView in your xml, you can get it and load an AdRequest. If you don't, the documentation's example adds one dynamically.

You also need to make sure you call .destroy(); on the view, so you'll want to override the onDestroy function. It's all in the documentation's example.